# SQL Server Query Getting Distinct Page_Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i get distinct `Page_Name` using this Query

```
   Select A.UserId,Page_Name,Region_Name, Content_Name,Chart_Src
   from  DWH_DBPages A 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashBoardA B ON A.sysRegionSno=B.sysRegionSno 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashBoardB C ON B.sysContentSno=C.sysContentSno 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashboardC D ON C.sysTypeSno=D.sysTypeSno
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashboardD E ON D.sysChartSno=E.sysChartSno
   WHERE A.UserId = 'xxxxxxxxx' AND A.sysMenuSno = 'xxxx'
```

Structure of Tables

```
DWH_DBPages A      
=============    
sysPageSno
Page_Name
sysMenuSno
Page_Status
Parent_Div
sysRegionSno
UserId
Created_Date


DWH_DashBoardA
==============
sysRegionSno
Region_Name
Region_Type
sysContentSno
UserId
Created_Date

DWH_DashboardC
===============
sysContentSno
Content_Name
sysTypeSno
UserId
Created_Date

DWH_DashboardD
===============
sysChartSno
Chart_Name
Chart_Src
Chart_Procedure
UserId
```

Comment: There is no column named Page_Name in your query.

Comment: How can we say that without knowing how these tables were defined in your DB, But I can say that you have not selected `Page_Name` anymore

Comment: Seems to be question about sql and not c#, correct the tags.

Comment: `Select distinct Page_Name from .......` thats all. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct( Page_Name) 
from (Select A.UserId,Page_Name,Region_Name, Content_Name,Chart_Src 
     from DWH_DBPages A 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashBoardA B ON A.sysRegionSno=B.sysRegionSno 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashBoardB C ON B.sysContentSno=C.sysContentSno 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashboardC D ON C.sysTypeSno=D.sysTypeSno 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN DWH_DashboardD E ON D.sysChartSno=E.sysChartSno 
     WHERE A.UserId = 'xxxxxxxxx' 
     AND A.sysMenuSno = 'xxxx')aa
```

Comment: Your query give this error
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: i miss aa :-) Thanks Revathi D

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT** a function. Putting the column names in parentheses is useless and unnecessary